# Preference for most acidic hydrogen

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I understand that deprotonation from the carbon circled in ***red*** is feasible because deprotonation results in a resonance-stabilised structure. But according to it, deprotonation is also feasible in ***blue***-circled carbon. Then why is that the ***red*** carbon hydrogens are more acidic?

Comment: Aldol reactions like this are thermodynamically controlled, so which hydrogen is most acidic isn't the issue here, it's which product is the most stable.

Comment: I can see here not two but *five* acidic centers. All of them would be deprotonated to some extent, but what comes later is important, as ortho said.